# Select option data binding angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I have problem in show data using select option:
No show error and show data in console, but nothing happend in screen user:

View

```html
HTML:

<select id="genero" class="form-control" #genero="" >
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option *ngFor="let genero of generos" [ngValue]="genero">{‌{genero.name}}</option>
</select>
```

component:

```html
export class:

public geneross: Generos[];



ngOnInit() {

this._generoService.getGeneros(this.token).subscribe(
response => {

this.generos = response.generos;



});
}
```

service:

```html
getGenereos(token){

let headers = new Headers({
'Content-Type':'application/json',
'Authorization':token
});

return this._http.get(this.url+'generos/', { headers: headers })
.map(res => res.json());
}
```

If I using :

```html
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let genero of generos" > {‌{genero.name}}</div>
```

List is work, but select option not work

Comment: From the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor) it would appear that you need to put `ngModel` on the select element. So I would update the open select tag to `<select id="genero" class="form-control" #genero ngModel>`

Comment: Thanks for help, there not anyone problem in the code, I found problem in my css. select: none;